# Error: dailyHLAReportDashboardController Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'Active' at line 6 column 201

Tags: apex, soql, query, dynamic-soql, compile-error

I am trying to query counts of an custom object records but i also need to filter out the records. so when i am using single quotes for where clause getting error as:

> Error: dailyHLAReportDashboardController Compile Error: expecting a
>   right parentheses, found 'Active' at line 6 column 201

I am trying to use below statement in visualforce controller.

```
Integer HLA_Signed_By_Customer = database.countQuery('Select id from Hardware_Loan_Agreement__c where CreatedDate>=:Date.today().addDays(-5) and CreatedDate<=:Date.today() and Primary_Status__c = 'Active'');
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You are having the exact same issue faced here: [What's wrong with this SOQL](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76053/whats-wrong-with-this-soql)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your quotes:

```
'... WHERE ... AND Primary_Status__c = \'Active\''
```

Or merge in a value:

```
String active = 'Active';
'... WHERE ... AND Primary_Status__c = :active'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer HLA_Signed_By_Customer = database.countQuery('Select id from Hardware_Loan_Agreement__c where CreatedDate>=:Date.today().addDays(-5) and CreatedDate<=:Date.today() and Primary_Status__c = 'Active'');
```

## Cannot Merge Apex Methods in Dynamic SOQL

You can't use things like `:Date.today().addDays(-5)` in Dynamic SOQL. You can only use simple variables. Instead, you would have to calculate the value ahead of time, or use an inline query.

## ''Active''

You have to "escape" single quotes, so you'd write `\'Active\'`. You can avoid this by using an inline query.

## Not Counting

You can only use Database.countQuery with `COUNT`, so you need to start off your query as `SELECT COUNT() FROM ...`.

## No Need to Calculate Dates in Apex

SOQL provides literals like TODAY and LAST_N_DAYS:5, so you can write "within the last five days" as "CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:5".

## Unnecessary filter

`CreatedDate <= TODAY` is always true; the created date will never be tomorrow or later.

---

It'd be lot easier if you used an inline query:

```
Integer HLA_Signed_By_Customer = [SELECT COUNT()
                                  FROM Hardware_Loan_Agreement__c
                                  WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:5 AND
                                        Primary_Status__c = 'Active'];
```